# Rails after_add association callback not triggering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my model, I have the line below included:

```
has_many :notes, as: :notable, dependent: :destroy, after_add: :create_informal_note
```

When I create a note associated to the model where the line above resides, I expect the `create_informal_note` method to fire.

However, the method is not being fired.

What's wrong here?

Potential Problem:

The `note` is being created from a HTTP request to `POST /api/v1/notes`.  In the request body's JSON, it includes `notable_id` and `notable_type`.  It's setting the actual fields, not setting `notable` as an object.

```
POST /api/v1/notes

{
  "note": {
    "text": "Test note",
    "notable_id": 1,
    "notable_type": "AnotherModel"
  }
}
```

And the output logs from my running Rails web server:

```
Processing by NotesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"note"=>{"notable_id"=>"1", "notable_type"=>"AnotherModel", "text"=>"Test note", "email"=>1, "documents_attributes"=>nil}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO `notes` (`text`, `notable_id`, `notable_type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Test note', 1, 'AnotherModel', '2016-02-19 11:32:56.401216', '2016-02-19 11:32:56.401216')
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
```

Could Rails be ignoring the association and hence the callback not triggering due to this?

Comment: does your method look like this ```create_informal_note(note)``` and have you confirmed in your testing that a new association has in fact been added and it didn't fail for some reason?

Comment: Yep, `def create_informal_note(note)`

Comment: Yes, I've verified the association is there.  Could it be because it's polymorphic?

Comment: Check my edit, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: lets continue this discussion in a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103987/create-informal-note)

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/115929). They say, that this callback is fired only when adding an object to the collection with `<<` method. I've tested a moment ago with a polymorphic collection and it worked only that way.

Comment: Ok, so that brings me to the question, how can I change my http request to set the `notable` as an object rather than send the fields in the request JSON?

Comment: @Mareq this would be an easy fix if I weren't creating the data via a request to a controller that uses strong params

Comment: I guess this has become more of a strong params question at this point though.

Answer (score 3):

This callback only works when adding the association via the << as per Mareq's comment above and the [thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/unable-to-get-has-many-after-add-to-work-need-help/110008/4) he mentioned.

Comment: In general, you'll want to ask people to post comments that answer the question as answers first, before posting it for them. If they haven't responded after a few days, or they say it's fine, you can post it yourself, but it's considered good form to let them do it first.

Comment: And when you do, it's better if you include the full answer rather than referencing the comment above. Please include the link to the thread - and the relevant parts in it.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, what is the best way to reach the original poster? Im relatively new to stackoverflow- I don't see a way to message the poster, nor am I allowed to comment on other's answers.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I didn't notice that you have low rep. Once you have 50, you'll be able to comment. Until then, you can feel free to write answers based on comments, as long as you credit the comment author and expand on it.

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth pointing out to future readers that this functionality is documented in the Active Record docs:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

```
# These callbacks are called only when the associated objects 
# are added or removed through the association collection:


# Triggers `before_add` callback
author.books << book
author.books = [book, book2]

# Does not trigger the `before_add` callback
book.update(author_id: 1)
```